# Python: List Index Out of Range / Append List

Tags: python, list, jupyter-notebook, append, for-in-loop

Here is my list sample **(data)**:
[Address list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ru51s.png)
Here is the snippet of the list:

```
['PO Box 4653, Stockton, California, 95204',
 '157 Adams St., Stockton, California, 95204', ...
```

Here is my **problem**:
[List index out of range (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mgbJT.png)
['int' object is not iterable (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljBWG.png)

Please note that solutions like `for i in a_list:` and `for i in range(len(a_list):` generates 'Error: list index out of range'

**Explanation**: 
My Address list has no nulls and I tried appending empty 'city_list' in a variety of ways as seen on the images... nothing seems to work. I am not sure how can I append my empty list - please help!

**Goal**: Grab 'a_list' and split each string in a for-in-loop, grab city value (index 1) and append it to an empty list 'city_list'

Comment: Avoid external links and include content in the question as properly formatted text.

Comment: In the iteration `i` is a number, `str(i)` produces a simple string, e.g. `"0"`.  Splitting that on ',' is obviously going to return a list, `["0"]`, which can only be indexed with `[0]`.  It should work better if you use `for astr in alist:` and `astr.split(',')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
a_list = ['PO Box 4653, Stockton, California, 95204','157 Adams St., Stockton, California']

city_list = []
for i in range(0,len(a_list)):
    city_name = a_list[i].split(",")[1].strip()
    city_list.append(city_name)

print(city_list)
```

Comment: The reason you are facing that error because you have written:
for i in (len(a_list)-1) : Here i is in integer value, so when you cast it to string it becomes "0" and when you split it ,It becomes ["0"] only one element because it doesn't have any comma in it . So when access the ["0"][1] it gives an error because the list is of 1 element. Either way the problem is in logic itself.

Comment: Your example works! However, there is a problem in my list apparently not in the loops...

Comment: Great, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to just try using a `for in` loop in the purest sense.

For instance, you can do

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for x in arr:
    print(x)
```

That should then print out

```
1
2
3
4
```

So in your case just use `for i in a_list`

Comment: Thanks, but your example is a bit too simple... In my case I'm trying to split a string in a list and append an empty list while in a for loop -> where the error appears. Your solution generates the same error, I'll add that image in my question.

Comment: Please read the body of my post -> Here is my problem: List index out of range (1) 'int' object is not iterable (2)'

Comment: I know it's probably difficult but is there any way that you could provide more on what else is going on in the notebook? With the small subset of data I have no issue pulling the cities out. I'm thinking that there may be a parsing error somewhere in the data that may be causing the indexing to get messed up. I can't really tell with only the 2 lines.

Comment: `arr = ['PO Box 4653, Stockton, California, 95204', '157 Adams St., Stockton, California, 95204']
arr = list(arr)

print(arr)

city_list = []

for address in arr:
    print(address)
    address = str(address).split(",")
    print(address)
    city = address[1]
    city_list.append(city)

print(city_list)`
Worked for me and pulled out Stockton twice.

Comment: It does work with this snippet of my list - you are right, weird! Something is wrong with my list I guess, not sure... I grab my values and assign it as `a_list=list(breweries_df.address)`, which is a column in a dataframe...

Comment: At some point in the data there's gotta be something that's being only returned as a single item in the list post-split. So then when you try and access the second spot in the array of split items it throws that error. I'd try and comb through your data to make sure it's consistent.

Comment: You were right, I found the problem - it was in the dataset itself. Because in my loop I was looking to append values at index [1], one row in the dataset did not have a value at that index, which was causing the loop to throw an error...

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide more context to your problem:

Number 1 does not work since you have an element from your list *without* a ','. Double check your data

Number 2 does not work since you're trying to iterate on an integer, which doesn't make sense. You need to make it a range, i.e. `range(len(a_list))`

If you *dont* care about the indices, just do:

```py
for address in a_list:
    # do something with address
```

It's simpler, more concise, and more intuitive. Always remember KISS: keep it simple stupid. Usually the simplest solution is the best.

Since you didn't provide us the data, you have to solve # 1 by yourself.

Comment: I am not sure what ' , ' you are noting here for number 1?

Comment: range(len(a_list)) creates the same - 'list out of range problem' . Also, you can see the data in the first image link... It's a list with address strings separated by a comma

Comment: @Dgomonov `x=i_split[1]` tries to get the second of the element of the string that you split using the comma ',' as the delimiter. It throws an error since `i_split[1]` does *not* exist. That means that there's an element in your data point that does not have a comma. Does this make sense?

Comment: What does this line return: `breweries_df.address.str.contains(',').value_counts()` ?